# react native android release apk is not receiving data from Internet

Tags: android, react-native, networkx

My React Native Application is not getting internet on some device.
The released application was build using ./gradlew bundleRelease and then ./gradlew assembleRelease. Application is fetching data from a remote server http://hptrade.unaux.com. Application is running smoothly on devices that i use in my house (4 android devices) but other devices not getting any data using my application. All the requests are GET and post request using XMLHttpRequest

I have tried by adding this line of code to my AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

This one also didn't helped

here is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nobabkhaan.hp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "HP",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.9",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.71.8",
    "react-native-compressor": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.6.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.9",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

If someone help me out I would be greatful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem. The problem was I was using HTTP But by default react components blocked HTTP. So I had to switch to HTTPS for APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Axios Try fetch

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But, I also tried that.